# Delphi: align and visibility of splitter

Tags: delphi, alignment, splitter

There is a tree view, an align is left. And there is a splitter, the same, an align is left. The tree view is the first, the slitter is the second.

If to do:

```
TreeView1.Visible:=false;
Splitter1.Visible:=false;
```

And then:

```
TreeView1.Visible:=true;
Splitter1.Visible:=true;
```

The splitter will be the first from the left. Must be the second. How to prevent this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to prevent this happening (even when you change the order of making them visible again, sometimes they still end up in wrong way). Add

```
Splitter1.Left := Treeview1.Left + Treeview1.Width;
```

after making them visible again, this should move splitter back into right position.

Comment: For other people finding this in a search, if you're doing this with right aligned controls, you need to do `Splitter1.Left := ClientWidth - Splitter1.Width - Treeview1.Width - 1`

Comment: @Nat For right aligned controls `Splitter1.Left := Treeview1.Left - 1;` should do.

Comment: @ain Sorry, yep, you're right... I was over engineering there!

Answer (score 2):

To make splitter second from the left you must make sure that TreeView is first on the left by setting:

```
TreeView1.Visible := True;
Splitter1.Visible := True;
Treeview1.Left := 0;
```